# CakePHP console doesn't work

Tags: cakephp, console

I am trying to get the CakePHP console working, but with no success.
I downloaded the latest package to `D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\`. I am using Windows 7 and I also set the environment variables (`D:\xampp\php\` and `D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\cake\console\`).
I am getting the error: `'cake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`
I hope it isn't a problem that I have xampp installed on the D: drive rather than C:

Thank you for any help!

Comment: location should not matter. did you close the prompt window and open it again?

Comment: Yes, did that. Anywhere I type 'cake' from, it brings me the same error. What could the problem be?

Comment: you should be typing it from the /app dir normally. the problem is windows is retarded :P try cd to php dir, then do php D:\cake\dir\bake

Comment: Looks like between the environment variables there should not be any empty space. That was the problem. Very weird indeed. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Maybe you should add what you wrote in the comment as the answer and mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like between the environment variables there should not be any empty space. That was the problem. Very weird indeed. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

I was the same problem. So I can able to solve:

Firstly, I tried this:
;'D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\';'D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\cake\console\';

and when I wrote 'cake' to the console, it wasn't working.

About one or two hours later I finnaly tried this, and it was working fine:

;D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\;D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\cake\console\;

Consequently: Don't use single or double quotation marks (' or "), and it will be working fine!

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the problem, check the above comments :)

Answer (score 1):

actually please check it that u have also included the" \ "after set the environment variable like this

```
        "D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\cake\console\)"
```

instead of like this

```
        "D:\xampp\htdocs\prj\cake\console)" same for the second one
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you. I've fixed the problem, check the above comments :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using wamp, It works for me. path variable to be set as

```
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\;c:\wamp\www\cake\console\;
```

Replace “c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\” with the location of your server’s php files and replace “c:\wamp\www\cake\console\” with the location of the cake\console folder of your current project.